# Does get_it have a real use with bloc?

Tags: flutter, bloc, get-it

The following code is part of a tutorial about Bloc:

**service_locator.dart**

```dart
final getIt = GetIt.instance;


void serviceLocatorInit() {
  getIt
    ..registerSingleton(UsernameCubit())
    ..registerSingleton(RouterSimpleCubit())
    ..registerSingleton(CounterCubit())
    ..registerSingleton(ThemeCubit())
    ..registerSingleton(GuestsBloc())
    ..registerSingleton(PokemonCubit())
    ..registerSingleton(HistoricLocationBloc())
    ..registerSingleton(
      GeolocationCubit(getIt<HistoricLocationBloc>().onNewUserLocation)..watchUserLocation()
    )
  ;
}
```

**main.dart**

```dart
void main() {
  serviceLocatorInit();
  runApp(const BlocsProviders());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appRouter = context.read<RouterSimpleCubit>().state;
    final theme = context.watch<ThemeCubit>().state;

    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme(isDarkmode: theme.isDarkMode).getTheme(),
      routerConfig: appRouter,
    );
  }
}


class BlocsProviders extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlocsProviders({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<UsernameCubit>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<RouterSimpleCubit>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<CounterCubit>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<ThemeCubit>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<GuestsBloc>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<PokemonCubit>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<GeolocationCubit>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<HistoricLocationBloc>()),
      ], 
      child: const MyApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

I have this question: is there some relevant use for `get_it` package in this code? because the author uses `context.read` or `BlocBuilder` for the rest of tutorial and in my opinion that makes irrelevant the use of `get_it` since **BlocProvider** already injects Bloc objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're totally right! [The creator of the `flutter_bloc` package himself advised against using `get_it`](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/3147#issuecomment-1016797991) to provide the instance of a Bloc or Cubit to a `BlocProvider` because it's already doing all the work of injecting your bloc:

> [...] I recommend **not mixing BlocProvider with get_it** but the immediate fix would be to change the bloc/cubit registrations to be factories instead of lazy singletons.
>
> *Felix Angelov, Jan 19, 2022*

The point of using a service locator is to simplify the replacement of an instance (often for testing) `BlocProvider` is already enough because you can already easily override the instance of a Bloc/Cubit you're refering to by wrapping your widget inside a new `BlocProvider`/`MultiBlocProvider`.

Personally, I use `get_it` to handle the injection of my repositories, use cases and datasources, but using it to inject the instance provided by a `BlocProvider` is just overkill and might even cause some weird behavior in some cases.

Comment: I see, you have mentioned another interesting point, how do you do it when you want a Bloc instance to be generated by a factory?

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα I'm not sure what you mean by that. `BlocProvider(create: ...)` is already a factory that will be called to create a new instance of your Bloc.
If you were talking about Felix's citation about "registering a factory", I think that he was referring to the `registerFactory` method from get_it.

Comment: If (Multi)BlocProvider is just an injector for BLoC/Cubit objects then, could they be replaced with calls to Get_it's registerFactory?