# How to get same instance of an object using a parameter such as ID, with getIt/injectable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, flutter-bloc, get-it

I am new to using `getIt` as dependancy injection, I used to use `Riverpod`. in riverpod we have `family providers`, where I can use an ID parameter to get the same instance of an object.
Now, in my current app, I'm working on a bookmarking feature using a  `cubit` , and I want to ensure that when I bookmark a post from any page, the update is reflected throughout the app wherever that specific post is displayed. I've created a cubit for bookmarking, and I'm trying to figure out how to obtain the same instance of the cubit based on the post ID using getIt.
Currently, when I call
`GetIt.instance<BookmarkCubit>(param1: post.id)` ,
it creates a new instance, and I'm unsure how to achieve the desired behavior of obtaining the same  `cubit`  instance across different pages. Any guidance on achieving this with  `getIt`  would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should provide code from getit where BookmarkCubit is created. probably, singlton approach should be used there

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi Thanks for your comment I will try to see if I can incorporate it. However, since each post needs a different instance of my cubit I don't think I can make it a singleton.

Comment: so you need the same instance of the cubit based on the post ID but you whant to use different instances of the one cubit otherwise? there is a suspicion that something is wrong here..
you need ONE сubit instance in app that will perform logic for different post IDs.

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi maybe I wasn't able to explain myself. I need to get the same instance based on the ID. So I will have multiple instances but whenever the id is for example 1, I want to get instance 'a' when Id is 2, get instance 'b',  and so on. I don't know if you have used Riverpod's dependency injection, but I can do exactly this, with riverpod's family provider. It accepts an input parameter and for the same parameter it always gives me the same instance. In a way it is a singleton in regards to the input. I have many instances but they are differentiated based on that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unlike in riverpod you don't need different instances of cubit. cubit has streams under the hood. here [more info](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts).
moreover, approach to use `get_it` for `cubit/bloc` creation is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286453/5243472).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was very useful. I'm gonna try and fix the issue