Flutter GetIt: compiler could not infer the registered bloc type
I'm trying to build authentication check into stateful widget with GETIT, BLOC and Cubit. First, I have dependency injected in init_dependencies.dart:
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

final serviceLocator = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> initDependencies() async {
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(() => AppUserCubit());
  _initAuth();
}

void _initAuth() async {
  serviceLocator
    ..registerFactory<AuthRemoteDataSource>(() => AuthRemoteDataSourceImpl(
          serviceLocator(),
        ))
    ..registerFactory<AuthRepository>(() => AuthRepositoryImpl(
          serviceLocator(),
        ))
    ..registerFactory(() => UserSignUp(
          serviceLocator(),
        ))
    ..registerFactory(() => UserLogin(
          serviceLocator(),
        ))
    ..registerFactory(() => CurrentUser(
          serviceLocator(),
        ))
    ..registerLazySingleton(() => AuthBloc(
          userSignUp: serviceLocator(),
          userLogin: serviceLocator(),
          currentUser: serviceLocator(),
          appUserCubit: serviceLocator(),
        )); 
}

And my main.dart looks like this:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initDependencies();
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => serviceLocator<AppUserCubit>(),
      ),
      BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => serviceLocator<AuthBloc>(),
      )
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthIsUserLoggedIn());
  }
}

But it throws an error at
context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthIsUserLoggedIn());

Error message:

'type !=null||const object() is! T': GetIt: The compiler not infer the type

I have:
environment:
  sdk: ^3.1.5
dependencies:
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.4
  get_it: ^7.6.7

I tried using registerLazySingletonAsync and registerFacotryAsync instead, but only got another error message that no such instance. It looks like the service dependency hasn't been initiated even with the await initDependencies();.

A suggestion related to bloc and get_it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286453/14071053

Thanks. As author mentioned, I removed the get_it layer on top and it all works.

Great to hear it's working now!
