Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type <?> is not registered inside GetIt
I'm learning Dependency Injection and Bloc. However, I have been facing an error that I cannot solve since last night.
When I run the callback function in the GenderAsset widget, the application gives an error.  When I use GenderCubit instead of Locator.sl(), the error goes away.
I leave the code and pages here. I'd be happy if you help.
Gender StflW
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => Locator.sl<GenderCubit>(),
      child: const _GenderView(),
    );
  }

Gender Widget
  body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const ProductPadding.ten(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              GenderAsset(
                value: false,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  print(context.read<GenderCubit>().genderValue); //error line
                },
                asset: AssetValue.female.value.lottie,
                gender: LocaleKeys.gender_fm.tr(),
                color: ProductColor().pink,
                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

init
@InjectableInit()
abstract final class Locator {
  static final sl = GetIt.instance;

  static Future<void> locateServices() async {
    sl.init();
  }
}

config
extension GetItInjectableX on _i174.GetIt { // initializes the registration of main-scope dependencies inside of GetIt   _i174.GetIt init({
    String? environment,
    _i526.EnvironmentFilter? environmentFilter,   }) {
    final gh = _i526.GetItHelper(
      this,
      environment,
      environmentFilter,
    );
    gh.lazySingleton<_i454.AppRouter>(() => _i454.AppRouter());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i46.BaseTheme>(() => _i46.BaseTheme());
    gh.factory<_i427.CacheMethods<_i906.BMIS>>(() => _i682.BMICache());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i162.ProductLocalization>(() => _i162.ProductLocalization(
          child: gh<_i409.Widget>(),
          key: gh<_i409.Key>(),
        ));
    gh.factory<_i427.CacheMethods<_i906.Users>>(() => _i575.UserCache());
    gh.factory<_i427.CacheMethods<_i906.Settings>>(() => _i138.AppCache());
    gh.factory<_i907.GenderCubit>(
        () => _i907.GenderCubit(genderValue: gh<_i110.GenderValue>()));
    return this;   } }

GenderValue
enum GenderValue {
  male,
  female,
}

GenderCubit
@injectable
class GenderCubit extends Cubit<GenderState> {
  GenderCubit({GenderValue? genderValue})
      : _genderValue = genderValue ?? GenderValue.male,
        super(SelectGender(genderValue: genderValue));

  GenderValue? _genderValue;

  GenderValue get genderValue => _genderValue!;

  void changeGender2() {
    print("changeGender2");
  }

  void changeGender({GenderValue? newGender}) {
    _genderValue = newGender;
    emit(SelectGender(genderValue: _genderValue));
  }
}


Could you please share the code of  GenderCubit?
May be you've missed the @injectable annotation for the cubit

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286453/14071053

Hello albert i added.
